# What does C standard say about a union of two identical types

Tags: c, types, unions

Is it possible to to have the following assert fail with any compiler on any architecture?

```
union { int x; int y; } u;
u.x = 19;
assert(u.x == u.y);
```

Comment: What does your title have to do with the question you're asking in the post? As to failing… since .x and .y occupy the same memory and are both treated as the same type, I don't see how the assert could fail unless `assert(u.x == u.x);` could fail.

Comment: There are several C standards. The answer to your question is very different if you are asking about C99TC2 or C99TC3, for instance (though I think that the idea of the technical corrigendum is that it only clarifies what the standard was saying all along).

Comment: @mah, I tried to give an example for the title and I believe they are at least related.

Comment: @mah: The fact that two things occupy the same memory and have the same type does not imply they appear to be equal in the C model. Consider `void foo(restrict int *a, restrict int *b) { *b = 3; assert(*b == *a); } int main(void) { int x; foo(&x, &x); return 0; }`. Although `*a` and `*b` refer to the same object in memory and have the same type, the assert may fail, because the C implementation is not required to “look up” `*a` in memory after assigning to `*b`. Similarly, were it not for the the fact that unions **are** required to reinterpret bytes, `u.x == u.y` could fail.

Comment: @EricPostpischil your argument changes the question around. In order to retain an apples-to-apples comparison you would have to `assert(b == a);` but by changing the term of the assertion to dereference pointers instead, you're now comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @mah: `*a` and `*b` are objects that occupy the same memory and have the same type. The fact that they are obtained via pointers is irrelevant to this fact; they are lvalues.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it's extremely relevant because you brought up C's lack of a requirement to re-read items it thinks it already knows the value of (when the volatile keyword is not used). It's a side argument to the actual issue. If you're trying to express that you or your knowledge is superior, I'll save you the trouble and agree with you on both counts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C99 Makes a special guarantee for a case when two members of a union are structures that share an initial sequence of fields:

```
struct X {int a; /* other fields may follow */ };
struct Y {int a; /* other fields may follow */ };
union {X x; Y y;} u;
u.x.a = 19;
assert(u.x.a == u.y.a); // Guaranteed never to fail by 6.5.2.3-5.
```

> **6.5.2.3-5 :** One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains
>   several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union
>   object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common
>   initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the complete type of the union is
>   visible. Two structures share a common initial sequence if corresponding members have
>   compatible types (and, for bit-fields, the same widths) for a sequence of one or more
>   initial members.

However, I was unable to find a comparable guarantee for non-structured types inside a union. This may very well be an omission, though: if the standard goes some length to describe what must happen with structured types that are not even the same, it should have clarified the same point for simpler, non-structured types.

Comment: One could argue that it shows that the committee considers it self-evident that type-punning from `int` to `int` does not change the value that it omitted to specify it near 6.5.2.3-5.

Comment: The case of accessing a union member other than the last one stored is  **explicitly** covered in C 2011 (N1570) note 95, which points to clause 6.2.6. Clause 6.5.2.3 has nothing to do with the matter.

Answer (score 4):

The `assert` in the problem will never fail in an implementation of standard C because accessing `u.y` after an assignment to `u.x` is required to reinterpret the bytes of `u.x` as the type of `u.y`. Since the types are the same, the reinterpretation produces the same value.

This requirement is noted in C 2011 (N1570) 6.5.2.3 note 95, which indicates it derives from clause 6.2.6, which covers the representations of types. Note 95 says:

> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation.

(N1570 is an unofficial draft but is [readily available on the net](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).)

Answer (score 3):

I believe this question is very hard to answer in the manner you seem to expect.

As far as I know, reading one field of a `union` that is not the one that was most recently wwritten to, is undefined behavior.

Thus, it's impossible to answer with "no", since any compiler writer is free to specifically detect this and make it fail just out of spite, if they feel like it.

Comment: There is this thing though: `A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.`

Comment: It is not undefined behavior. The C standard, since 1999 TC3 at least, requires that accessing a union member other than the last one stored reinterpret the bytes as a valued of the accessed type. See draft N1570 6.5.2.3 note 95 or N1256 note 82.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This is footnote 82 and it only was published in the TC3 revision of C99.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, agreed. But if we create a pointer to u, it should point to the first byte of x, and also the first byte of y?